# getting error when installing apk on android 13

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am trying install an apk on android 13 devices, but I am getting error: `There was a problem while parsing the package`. I am not sure why I am getting this error on android 13... apk is getting installed on other lower android versions.

in build.gradle

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
}
```

Please tell me if any other details are required to resolve this issue

Comment: change `targetSdkVersion` 31 to 33 and remove `buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly corrupted apk file. If you haven't tried downloading the same apk file again then I'd first suggest doing that. If the problem still persists then a great place to start is by using  androids own debugging tools while reproducing the error as androids debugging tools take note of everything happening in that instance allowing you to look the data obtained and then diagnosing the problem to learn what exactly the issues are. Start by going to the website linked below and download androids debugging tools, but first your gonna need to learn how to use it so don't forget to do a little reading on this website, everything you'd need to know about androids adb tools is all right here on this site.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb